# Azure scale set autoscale custom image

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, azure

How can I create a VM scale set with a custom Windows Server 2012 image with autoscale enabled?

I found azure templates which create scale sets + custom image and another which creates scale set with autoscaling. However I need to combine scale set, auto scaling and custom image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can modify the template, here is my [template](https://github.com/yejason/Jason/blob/master/jasontest2.json).

```
PS C:\windows\system32> New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name ExampleDeployment -ResourceGroupName ExampleResourceGroup -TemplateFile c:\Users\Desktop\jasontest2.json

cmdlet New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
(Type !? for Help.)
sourceImageVhdUri: https://jasontestdisks591.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/jasonvm20170227164237.vhd
vmssName: jason786
instanceCount: 3
adminUsername: jason
adminPassword: ************


DeploymentName          : ExampleDeployment
ResourceGroupName       : ExampleResourceGroup
ProvisioningState       : Succeeded
Timestamp               : 2/27/2017 9:38:24 AM
Mode                    : Incremental
TemplateLink            :
Parameters              :
                          Name             Type                       Value
                          ===============  =========================  ==========
                          vmSku            String                     Standard_D1
                          sourceImageVhdUri  String                     https://jasontestdisks591.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/jasonvm20170227164237.vhd
                          vmssName         String                     jason786
                          instanceCount    Int                        3
                          adminUsername    String                     jason
                          adminPassword    SecureString

Outputs                 :
DeploymentDebugLogLevel :
```

We can modify the auto scale settings [here](https://resources.azure.com/).
More information about configure and update the autoscale setting for a scale set, refer to the [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/insights-advanced-autoscale-virtual-machine-scale-sets).

Answer (score 0):

There is an azure-quickstart-template named [201-vmss-windows-customimage](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vmss-windows-customimage) that will give you a template to accomplish this.

From the readme.md

> Deploy a VM Scale Set based on a Windows Custom Image
>
> This template deploys a VM Scale Set from a user provided Windows
>   Custom Image
>
> The template allows a URL to a custom image to be provided as a
>   parameter at run time. The custom image should be contained in a
>   storage account which is in the same location as the VM Scale Set is
>   created in, in addtion the storage account which contains the image
>   should also be under the same subscription that the scale set is being
>   created in.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I came across that template, however this template does not provide the functionality to autoscale.

Answer (score 0):

[Scale Set template](https://github.com/krnese/AzureDeploy/blob/master/VMScaleSets/azuredeploy.json)

The following template should allow you to created the desired scaleset, its uses a Blob url to specify the VHD.